# How to use cordova plugin file with quasar vue

Tags: android, cordova, vuejs3, cordova-plugins, quasar

It's been a day I'm not able to find a way to understand how this stuff work, and I'm unable to find anything on the web about it.

The idea is simple, when my app start I want to be able to create a directory on my phone if it does not exists, later I want to add json files in this directory and be able to read them to load data into components, and if I can access those json from my computer by usb file sharing and edit them myself it's better !

For this I'm using quasar with cordova file plugin, I've edited the `IndexPage.vue` the following way.

I've set up `cordova` and `cordova-plugin-file` following the quasar doc https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/preparation/

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage',
  components: { MyAppComponent },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.cordova_is_ready, false)
  },
  methods: {
    cordova_is_ready() {
      const app_dir = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory
      app_dir.getDirectory('MyAppDir', { create: true }, (dirEntry) => { console.log("Created") })
    }
  },
  setup() {
    return { };
  },
});
</script>
```

But doing it, when launching my App I got the page displaying correctly but no clue if `MyAppDir` was created correctly or not and was not able to find it anywhere on my phone, I've also tested with others type of `cordova.file.<file type>` (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) but it did not succeed.

PS: I know I use snake case in TS but let's not focus on that please